# How can I execute a JS script file from Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a MapReduce job for my MongoDB database implemented in a Javascript script file.  I've tested it from the commandline and Mongo shell (`load("MR_stack.js")`).  Now I'm using Pymongo  within a larger application to access the Mongo database.  How can I execute my `MR_stack.js` script from within Pymongo?

Answer (score 7):

The database object has an `eval` method:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html

Comment: (UPDATE 6.2016) Now as documentation says: *Warning: the eval command is deprecated in MongoDB 3.0 and will be removed in a future server version.*

Answer (score 0):

from bson import Binary, Code

You can use this library for running your javascript mapreduce code like this

```
map = code("""your mapreduce code""")

reducer = code("""your mapreduce code""")

emp = db.orders.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, "moid_details")
```