# Accessing MongoDB document fields within pymongo find() function

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to access some document field from within the pymongo find() method and pass that into a function in my python script, I've tried something like this:

```
def some_python_function(input):
    # some calculations
    return some_int_based_on_input

cursor = col.find(
    {
        "$where" : "some_python_function(this.some_field_in_document) > 2000"
    }
)
```

But with no luck. Is it possible for a python script to access document fields from within a find(), or do I have to do the query first and filter the results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230794/how-can-i-execute-a-js-script-file-from-pymongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use the pymongo library to "send" a script that will be executed.

There used to be an "eval" function but it got deprecated.
Read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/

Comment: Oh well, thanks for the quick reply! At least I can stop trying to figure it out.